# Connection string for Sql web server

Tags: c#, .net, cpanel

I've created a database in my cpanel and created table as well.I just want that table to connect to my project.What should i do in config file connection string to connect it.How can i get my connection string from web server.??
My web.config is as :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=ISL-4;Initial  Catalog=Cruisedb;Integrated Security=True"  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,  PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
   <customErrors mode="Off"/>       
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Need to add user name and password in connectionString. What is the error you got? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178411.aspx

Comment: Thanku brother..just needed to add credentials of database..that helped :)

Answer (score 1):

```
ConnectionStringSettings mySetting = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"];
if (mySetting == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(mySetting.ConnectionString))
    throw new Exception("Fatal error: missing connecting string in web.config file");
conString = mySetting.ConnectionString;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ConfigurationManager class for implementing this.
i think this link is useful for you

[ConfigurationManager Class(MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You  can retrieve your connection string as follows:

```
string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
```

**Note**: For using `ConfigurationManager` you need to add `System.Configuration` as a **reference** in your solution if it is not added. Also add the following using directive

```
using System.Configuration;
```

Advice : You should keep the `name` of the connectionstring in web.config something meaningful like CruiseConStr.